# SELECT INTO OUTFILE only giving column names in csv

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a query that will get me a csv with headers, I have that query running with no issues as:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT *
FROM tt1
WHERE (col1 = '12345')
AND
col2 BETWEEN 
CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AND 
CAST('2021-03-31' AS DATE)
    )
) resulting_set
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Exports/changeme.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

And this outputs a csv as desired, but my table has 63 columns so I want to limit what columns are exported. I thought that

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'col1','col2'
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT 'col1','col2'
FROM tt1
WHERE (col1 = '12345')
AND
col2 BETWEEN 
CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AND 
CAST('2021-03-31' AS DATE)
    )
) resulting_set
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Exports/changeme.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Would get me what I want but, the csv I get doesn't have data but just the header name repeated in the cells like below.

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| col1 | col2 |
| col1 | col2 |
| col1 | col2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because your second query has single quotes around the column names and so mysql treats that as string

'Please read before you go on this thread [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'col1','col2'
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT `col1`,`col2`
FROM tt1
WHERE (col1 = '12345')
AND
col2 BETWEEN 
CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AND 
CAST('2021-03-31' AS DATE)
    )
) resulting_set
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Exports/changeme.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```